# moving player right or left depending on swipe

Tags: java, android

In my Player.java class, I want to incorporate a function that moves my player according to the left or right swipes. I also used time in seconds in order to vary the movement in an cyclic way:

```
'''
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:00"));
            Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm");
            date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:00"));
            String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    X-=K;
                    int currentSeconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    Y=Y*Math.cos(18.currentSeconds);
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    X+=K;
                    int currentSeconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    Y=Y*Math.cos(18.currentSeconds);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
'''
```

After some research, this is the class I included in player.java. So my question is: Is there a more efficient way to detect swiping directions(without creating any additional class) and what is your opinion about the code structure knowing that the objective is to change X according to swipe direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some local variables and make them static variables, why ? because these are created and destroyed if you use serveral times the method `onFling`. The main Idea is to improve the performance and decrease the space your method uses.

Also I refactorized some pieces of code

```java
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm");
        private static Calendar cal;        

        MyGestureDetector() {
            date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:00"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:00"));
            String localTime = date.format(cal.getTime());
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    X -= K;
                    Y *= Math.cos(18*cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)); //18 * currentSeconds i think
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    X += K;
                    Y *= Math.cos(18*cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Perhaps if the program does nothing or have an unexpected behavior
                // you are silencing the cause (it has happened to me)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Hope it helped.